# What are the units used in $\nabla^a F_{ab}=-4\pi j_b$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, general-relativity, dimensional-analysis, units

I'm studying Wald's general relativity, in it Wald mentions that the Maxwell's equation is equivalent to $dF=0$ and $\nabla^a F_{ab}=-4\pi j_b$, where $F$ is the Maxwell two form. Wald doesn't explicity give an expression for $F$, but I'm assuming it's $F=E_xdx\wedge dt+E_y dy\wedge dt+E_z dz\wedge dt+B_x dy\wedge dz+B_y dz\wedge dx+B_z dx\wedge dy.$ My question is: what units is Wald using here?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to answer your own question, by letting $b=t$, and then:

$\nabla^{a}F_{at} = \eta^{ab}\left(\partial_{a}\phi -\partial_{t}A_{a}\right) = -{\vec \nabla}\cdot {\vec E} = -4\pi \rho $

So, what units for Q make this work out, when compared with the standard Maxwell equations?  (remembering that $c=1$)

Comment: It seems we are taking $\epsilon_0=1/4\pi$ and $c=1$, and it looks like a hybrid of Gaussian and natural units here. Do we have a name for that?